# como alterar valor de input number

Tags: javascript, html, front-end, dom

Estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades para alterar o valor de uma input (conforme o enunciado da pergunta).

**Segue abaixo o código:**

```js
function alteraQtdProduto(op) {
  if (op == 'up') {
    var num = document.getElementById('setQtdProduto').value;
                                document.getElementById('setQtdProduto').textContent = num++;

  }
}
```

```css
.cart_qtd {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center">

  <button type="button" onclick="alteraQtdProduto('down')">-  </button>

  <input id="setQtdProduto" class="cart_qtd" type="number" value="1" min="1">

  <button type="button" onclick="alteraQtdProduto('up')">+</button>

</div>
```

**O que era pretendido:**

- ao clicar no botão + era para o valor na input ser alterado.
  tentei implementar apenas a parte de aumentar os itens até o momento.

**P.S.:** Só tentei implementar o botão de + itens até o momento.

Comment: Aparece algum erro no console do navegador, quando vc tenta incrementar ou quando a página carrega?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Seu elemento é um `<input>`. Da mesma forma que usou o atributo `.value` para obter o valor, é esse atributo que você deve utilizar para definir o novo valor, ao invés do `textContent`.
2. `.value` retorna uma string. É necessário fazer a conversão com `parseInt` ou `parseFloat` antes de realizar a adição.
3. Como está usando o mesmo elemento, pode-se criar uma variável apontando para o mesmo. Ao invés de chamar `getElementById` diversas vezes.

```js
const qtdProduto = document.getElementById('setQtdProduto');

function alteraQtdProduto(op) {
  if (op == 'up') {
    var num = parseInt(qtdProduto.value);
    qtdProduto.value = num + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="alteraQtdProduto('down')">-  </button>

  <input id="setQtdProduto" class="cart_qtd" type="number" value="1" min="1">

  <button type="button" onclick="alteraQtdProduto('up')">+</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Boa, funcionou. Eu pensei nisso, porém utilizei o typeof no valor que peguei da input e ele retornou um number, por isso desconsiderei :/